# How to get JPQL queries autocompolete for me in Eclipse3.5

Tags: eclipse, jpa, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, jpql

How to get JPQL queries autocompoleted for me in Eclipse.

(note: Idon't want to use thrid party tools, BTW, JBoss Hibernate tools cannot work with me, I think it needs hibernate specific files to start working(hibernate.cfg.xml etc.))

EDIT:
Iam using Eclipse 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does not currently have a JPQL editor (auto-complete, syntax highlighting, etc.). There is a project that is just getting started in JPA Tools project (under WTP) to build such an editor, but this will not be available at least until Eclipse 3.7 (Summer 2011).

Third parties may have such an editor, but I do not how that might be or how good they are.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled JPA facet on your EJB project? See at right click on project/project facets.

Comment: Yes I did and so, I get table/columns names autocompolete when writting the annotations

Answer (score 0):

Beware that this feature will only be available for NamedQuery annotations from Eclipse 3.7 Milestone 7 :
http://bugs.eclipse.org/337930

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse Marketplace from the Help menu and search for JBoss Tools. From the whole list of tools, select Base and Hibernate Tools. See pic.
[image]